# My shadow layer vanishes when I blur 1 using field blur

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blur, drop-shadow

I have an object layer to which I want to add a realistic shadow.
I found a tutorial on youtube (https://youtu.be/5TuhBcN9k8w) and am following it to create the shadow.
I have created a dropshadow, turned it into a layer, flipped in vertically and skew it to the right angle. So far no issues.
In the next step I'm supposed to add two field blur points (with the shadow layer selected)
Here's where I can no longer further complete the job.

The issue:
I am in the field blur menu and have just added a blur point to the layer. Now, when I use the blur eye to increase the blur, my shadow layer disappears completely after an increase of just 1 blur. In effect I'm unable to blur anything.

It must be a setting that's wrong, but for the life of me I can't figure out which, nor did I find topics on the internet concerning the same issue.

So I hope someone here can help me out here.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's hard to say. I tried following the steps in the tutorial and it seems to work as expected, and I was unable reproduce the issue you describe. [here's a screenshot](https://imgur.com/1uMJ3qp).  Can you check through the steps yourself, and make sure you are following them exactly?  If that doesn't work, perhaps try temporarily switching off the "Use Graphics Processor" setting in Preferences > Performance.  If this works for you, it could point to an issue with your graphics card such as outdated drivers or some graphics card incompatibility issue.